# Prevent each vstfs link from opening a new instance of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server

We have a code review report which shows open code reviews; who raised it, what the state is and whether it has comments. Each row in the report has a link similar to the one below

`vstfs:///CodeReview/Request/130812?url=https://tfs.ourdomain.com/DefaultCollection/`

When you click the link to open a code review request in Visual Studio,  the below prompt appears.

[image]

When you click "Open..." a new instance of VS is loaded every time. Is there a way to force the OS to always use the existing instance of VS, if it's already running?

Comment: The following link is an answer from two and half years ago where it states this is not currently supported and that there is a uservoice suggestion open for it. I couldn't find this uservoice suggestion but if judging by your post, I assume they still haven't implemented this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397878/open-vstfs-url-from-running-instance-of-visual-studio

Comment: Given the comment by @Oast, maybe the following helps: https://superuser.com/a/316563/714576

Comment: Within the existing instance of VS, how would you go about opening the vstfs link by doing close and open in VS?

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure I understand you follow up question. I can click a vstfs link and open an instance of visual studio, close it, then click the next vstfs link. This doesn't get me any further though. I want the vstfs link to use the already running instance, and refresh the code review panel in visual studio. I don't think it can be done, based on the comment from 1NN.

Comment: What I meant is: From the running instance, can you open the vstfs link if (for example) you copied it to the clipboard? And are you on Windows?

Comment: No, I have to use a different code review search tool inside Visual Studio. Yes, Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like the answer is negative.

I reproduce here the Stack Overflow answer for the question which attacked
the problem from another angle:
[Open vstfs url from running instance of Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56456944/165358).

> I am afraid there is no such way we could open vstfs url in existing
> Visual Studio instance.
>
> There is a user voice about it (*Since the old visual studio uservoice
> forum is deactivated, I could not post the link here.* )
>
> [image]
>
> If it is important to you, you can open a [new ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8) here:
>
> [image]
>
> You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are
> enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the
> product team member will take this feedback seriously.

The link in the answer has changed and is currently
[Visual Studio - Request a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion)
(requires sign-in).